# How to prove one theorem related to Stoke`s theorem

Tags: curl

Stock`s theorem $$\oint\limits_C {{\bf{a}} \cdot {\bf{dr}}}  = \iint\limits_S {\nabla  \times {\bf{a}}\, \cdot {\bf{n}}dA}$$

Substituting ${\bf{a}} = {\bf{f}} \times {\bf{c}}$
we find that $$\oint\limits_C {{\bf{dr}} \times {\bf{f}}}  = \iint\limits_S {\left( {{\bf{n}} \times \nabla \,} \right) \times {\bf{f}}dA}$$
since
${\bf{n}} \cdot \left( {\nabla   \times \left( {{\bf{f}} \times {\bf{c}}} \right)} \right) = {\bf{c}} \cdot \left( {\left( {{\bf{n}} \times\nabla  } \right) \times {\bf{f}}} \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYfdmGievaebbnrfi
% fHhDYfgasaacH8srps0lbbf9q8WrFfeuY-Hhbbf9v8qqaqFr0xc9pk
% 0xbba9q8WqFfea0-yr0RYxir-Jbba9q8aq0-yq-He9q8qqQ8frFve9
% Fve9Ff0dmeaabaqaciGacaGaaeqabaWaaeaaeaaakeaacaWHUbGaey
% yXIC9aaeWaaeaadaWhcaqaaiabgEGirdGaay51GaGaey41aq7aaeWa
% aeaacaWHMbGaey41aqRaaC4yaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaGaayjkaiaawM
% caaiabg2da9iaahogacqGHflY1daqadaqaamaabmaabaGaaCOBaiab
% gEna0oaaFiaabaGaey4bIenacaGLxdcaaiaawIcacaGLPaaacqGHxd
% aTcaWHMbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaaaa!55F5!
$

I can`t prove last equation, please help,

**c** is constant vector,
**n** is unit vector,
**a** and **f** are vector functions

Comment: $f$ is a function? $n$ a unit vector? What is $n\times\nabla$? In any case it appears be a trivial (but long) calculation.

Comment: Yes, f is vector function, n is unit vector, $${\bf{n}} \times \nabla 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaCOBaiabgE
% na0kabgEGirdaa!3A8A!
$$ is a cross product.

Comment: And what is the "cross product" of vector $\times$ *operator*?

Comment: It`s a vector operator ${\bf{n}} \times \nabla  = {n_i}{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_i} \times {{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j}{\partial _j} = {{{\bf{\hat e}}}_k}{\varepsilon _{ijk}}{n_i}{\partial _j}$